# Varnish with Nginx for a Rails application (issue with Devise authentication)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, nginx, devise, varnish

I have the following configuration for Varnish. But when I access the application, it doesn't ask for login, it just login.
What I'm doing wrong?

default.vcl

```
backend default {
 .host = "127.0.0.1";
 .port = "80";
}


sub vcl_recv { 
     if(req.url ~ "sign_in" || req.url ~ "sign_out" || req.request == "POST" || req.request == "PUT" || req.request == "DELETE") {
    return (pass);
    }
    return (lookup);
}

sub vcl_fetch {
if(req.url ~ "logout" || req.url ~ "sign_out"){
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
}
if (req.request == "GET") {
       unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
       set beresp.ttl = 360m;
}

if (req.url ~ "images/" || req.url ~ "javascripts" || req.url ~ "stylesheets" || req.url ~ "assets"){
       set beresp.ttl = 360m;
}
}
```

/etc/default/varnish

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a 192.241.136.37:80 \
         -T localhost:6082 \
         -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
         -S /etc/varnish/secret \
         -s malloc,256m"
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
 upstream app {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
listen 80;
client_max_body_size 2G;
server_name localhost;
keepalive_timeout 5;
root /home/deploy/apps/wms/current/public;
access_log  off;
error_log off;

if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|PUT|POST|DELETE|OPTIONS)$ ){
    return 405;
}

location ~ ^/(assets)/  {  
    gzip_static on;
    expires     max;
    add_header  Cache-Control public;
} 

location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
    error_page 404              /404.html;
    error_page 422              /422.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /500.html;
    error_page 403              /403.html;
}

location @app {
    proxy_pass http://app;
}

location = /favicon.ico {
    expires    max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    deny  all;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are preventing your backend to delete your session cookie, so you can't log out unless you explicitly delete your browsers' cookies.

Looking at your fetch VCL (Comment inline):

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  # This prevents server from deleting the cookie in the browser when loging out
  if(req.url ~ "logout" || req.url ~ "sign_out"){
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
  }
  if (req.request == "GET") {
    unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
    set beresp.ttl = 360m;
  }
  if (req.url ~ "images/" || req.url ~ "javascripts" || req.url ~ "stylesheets" || req.url ~ "assets"){
    set beresp.ttl = 360m;
  }
}
```

So your backend can't delete client's cookie unless as result of a POST request.

IMHO you shouldn't mess with backend's Set-Cookie headers unless you know (and test well) posible side effects

Comment: I'm new to varnish. Should I remove that line? What should I do?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the issue will be avoided if you remove/comment the first if block and reload/restart varnish